# Is this list punctuated correctly?

Tags: dashes, colons

I am in the process of writing my CV/Resume and want to list my skills with a brief explanation of how I learnt them. So far I have been using:

- Marketing Experience - Gained from owning a small online business.
- Flexible Worker - A basic requirement of my previous role as a
  general assistant.
- IT Skills - Gained from 2 years of software development as a hobby.
- etc...

Is this correct? I thought about using a colon instead of the dash but would that be grammatically incorrect?

Comment: @ElendilTheTall Thanks, I would love to do that but I'm already pushing fitting it onto 2 pages!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that's absolutely fine. You could alternatively put a line break in and make each skill/experience a subheading. Good luck with the job hunt!

Comment: Thanks! Is it also fine to capitalise both 'Marketing' and 'Experience' as well as the 'Gained'?

Comment: I wouldn't capitalise anything but the first word of each paragraph